Why is compactness necessary for IVT
The version of IVT I am working with is as follows:
Let $f\colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function from a compact subset of the real line, and suppose that $f(a) \lt 0$ and $f(b) \gt 0$ . Then there exists $c \in [a, b]$ such that $f(c) = 0$
I can see how this would fail if we were working with a (finite) open interval rather than a closed one, but why would our interval need to be bounded?

We need to have end points $a,b$, otherwise the theorem doesn't make sense. Of course, in any interval $I$ you can always choose points $a<b$ in $I$, and apply the theorem in the subinterval $[a,b]$.

Compactness is "necessary" because we have points $a,b$, and we apply the theorem to the (compact) set $[\min{a,b},\max{a,b}]$. However, boundedness is not necessary. The theorem applies in the case that $a=-\infty$ and/or $b=\infty$, as long as we have continuity at the endpoints. Typically this takes the form of $f(-\infty)=\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)$ definitionally, and/or $f(\infty)=\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$.

If the interval was not compact, then the endpoints would not be in the domain of $f$, and so talking about $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ would not make sense. As a direct consequence of your theorem, however, you of course have the following:

Theorem. Let $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be an interval, and let $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $a,b\in I$ are such that $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>0$, then $f(c)=0$ for some point $c$ between $a$ and $b$.

Note that the above says nothing about the interval except that it is an interval. It is really just a matter of applying the theorem to the interval $[a,b]\subseteq I$ though, and so it does not really say anything else than your theorem.

Exactly. The IVT is about preserving connectedness and the connected subsets of the real line are exactly the intervals.
